# How to use enum? java

Tags: java, enums, constants

I heard about enums type and I looked it up online, but I couldn't find a good explanation in how it is better than using constant. Could anyone explain how is it better than using constants and how to use it in the following code if we wanted to apply it:

(lets use it to define the following data from my poker card class:

`- enum Suit {HEARTS, DIAMONDS, SPADES, CLUBS}
- enum Face {ACE, JACK, QUEEN, KING}`

```
public class Card {

    final static int MAX_SUITS = 4;
    final static int MAX_FACE_VALUES = 13;

    private int suit;
    private int faceValue;

    public Card(int faceValue, int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public int getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public int getFaceValue() {
        return faceValue;
    }
    public void setSuit(int suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public void setFaceValue(int faceValue) {
        this.faceValue = faceValue;
    }

    public String convertSuitToString() {
        if (this.suit >= 1 && this.suit <= 4) {
            if (this.suit == 1)
                return "HEARTS";
            else if (this.suit == 2)
                return "DIAMONDS";
            else if (this.suit == 3)
                return "SPADES";
            else if (this.suit == 4)
                return "CLUB";
        }
        return "((Invalid Suit Entry))";
    }

    public String convertFaceToString() {
        if (this.faceValue >= 1 && this.faceValue <= 13) {
            if (this.faceValue == 1)
                return "ACE";
            else if (this.faceValue >= 2 && this.faceValue <= 10)
                return this.faceValue + "";
            else if (this.faceValue == 11)
                return "JACK";
            else if (this.faceValue == 12)
                return "QUEEN";
            else if (this.faceValue == 13)
                return "KING";
        }
        return "((Invalid Face Value Entry))";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "You got " + convertFaceToString() + " of " + convertSuitToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: constants are generally undefined and difficult to control, an enum gives you much tighter control over what are the acceptable values and class or method might expect, rather than using, say an `int`

Comment: `Enums`  and `Constants` are NOT the same thing...  your question makes it sound like one is a complement of the other; they aren't necessarily that.  A `constant` has one value, that is _constant_ and an `enumeration` can have _multiple_ values that you can assign as you need to.

Comment: *"how it is better than using constant"* This is explained by [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

Comment: Simply: they are type safe, and in the Java scenario, they can be enriched with behavior (and members).

Comment: I hope I can get help more than getting uncertain judgments. I choose to share my questions here in Stack overflow to get help from people who know how to help, not to go through the smart detective member. after-all, we all are members here, and we all are seeking the same purpose. TO LEARN FROM OUR MISTAKES. If I am willing to cheat or whatever these people think,  I could have done it in many different ways. So, please, try to help, or just stop being a block for those who are seeking help!

Answer (score 0):

> Could anyone explain how is it better than using constants ?

One is not better than the other, just different. Here is some advantages of the `enum`.

---

**Enum**

- Can be used in `switch` statements
- Provide useful method, see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html)
- Could be represented as a `class` full of `constants`
- Type safety, with a `constants` you can use `unallowed` value, while the `enum` force you to use it properties.
- `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` classes

Example :

```
//Supported color constants
public static final int RED = 1;
public static final int BLUE = 2;

setColor(3);//would compile, but would fail later.
```

While an `enum` would force you to take it values.

Comment: @askd Did this answer help you understand more ?